# Customize TestCafe Selector in TypeScript for Shadow root Element

Tags: typescript, automated-tests, e2e-testing, shadow-dom, testcafe

Please help me to define `Selector` part in TypeScript

```js
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe'

fixture `Scenario Name : Validation`
    .page `https://chrisbateman.github.io/guide-to-web-components/demos/shadow-dom.htm`;


const demoPage  = Selector('#demo1');
const paragraph = Selector(() => {
    return demoPageSelector().shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('p');
}, { dependencies: { demoPageSelector: demoPage } });


test('Test ShadowDom', async t => {
    await t
        .expect(paragraph.value).eql('Some text');
});
```

Comment: Hi, is it a duplicate of [How will customize selector for an element in shadow root for type script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57974960/how-will-customize-selector-for-an-element-in-shadow-root-for-type-script) and [How to create a customise Selector in Type script for an element within shadow root](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57982325/how-to-create-a-customise-selector-in-type-script-for-an-element-within-shadow-r)?

Answer (score 1):

Hi [Debashish Samanta](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11899153/debashish-samanta),

Dependencies are added to the function's scope at runtime, so TypeScript cannot find them during compilation. You can suppress this validation using the `// @ts-ignore` comment.

As for the "Argument of type '{ dependencies: { demoPageSelector: Selector; }; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SelectorOptions'." error, it seems like the `dependencies` property is somehow missing in the `SelectorOptions` type declaration. You can work around this using the `<SelctorOptions>` type assertion.

```
import { Selector, t } from 'testcafe'

fixture `Scenario Name : Validation`
    .page `https://chrisbateman.github.io/guide-to-web-components/demos/shadow-dom.htm`;


const demoPage  = Selector('#demo1');
const paragraph = Selector(() => {
    // @ts-ignore: Cannot find name 'demoPageSelector'.
    return demoPageSelector().shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('p');
}, <SelectorOptions> { dependencies: { demoPageSelector: demoPage } });


test('Test ShadowDom', async t => {
    await t
        .expect(paragraph.innerText).eql('These paragraphs are in a shadow root.');
});
```